# When are log complexities considered equivalent?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

Would we consider $O(\log_2(n))$ to be the same complexity as $O(\log_2(n-1))$?

Why or why not? I'm specifically wondering about how the number we take the log of affects the time complexity.

Comment: Note that Landau notation does not per se have anything to do with time complexity. "$O(f)$" is a mathematical construct that _can_ be used to reason about algorithmic costs and complexities; but you're interested in domain-independent properties.

Answer (score 3):

$O(\log(n))$ and $O(\log(n-1))$ contain the same set of functions.

The inclusion $O(\log(n-1)) \subseteq O(\log(n))$ is trivial.
As for $O(\log(n-1)) \supseteq O(\log(n))$, let $f(n) \in O(\log(n))$ and let $c \ge 1$ and $n_0 \ge 3$ be such that:
$$
f(n) \le c \log(n) \quad \forall n \ge n_0.
$$

We have:
$$
f(n) \le c \log(n) = c + c \log(n/2) \le c + c \log(n-1) \le 2c \log(n-1).
$$

Showing that $f(n) \in O(\log(n-1))$.